# error with using memcpy

Tags: c++, matlab

I try to connect c++ to matlab  for figure function. for the example

```
Engine *m_pEngine;
m_pEngine = engOpen("null"); //open matlab engine

const int arraysize = 1000;
const double degTorad = .0174;

double SinArray[arraysize];
double CosArray[arraysize];
double Degrees[arraysize];
for (int iii = 0; iii < arraysize; iii++)
{
Degrees[iii] = iii;//gets the degree
SinArray[iii] = sin(iii*degTorad);
CosArray[iii] = cos(iii*degTorad);

}
cout << "Example 1 or 2?"<<"\n";
char Sim = '1';
cin >> Sim;

// example 1 below
// we will pass an entire array to be plotted

if (Sim == '1')
{
mxArray* SIN = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(arraysize, 1, mxREAL);
memcpy((void *)mxGetPr(SIN), (void *)SinArray, sizeof(double)*arraysize);
engPutVariable(m_pEngine, "SinGraph", SIN);

mxArray* COS = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(arraysize, 1, mxREAL);
memcpy((void *)mxGetPr(COS), (void *)CosArray, sizeof(double)*arraysize);
engPutVariable(m_pEngine, "CosGraph", COS);

mxArray* DEG = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(arraysize, 1, mxREAL);
memcpy((void *)mxGetPr(DEG), (void *)Degrees, sizeof(double)*arraysize);
engPutVariable(m_pEngine, "Degrees", DEG);

engEvalString(m_pEngine, "figure('units','normalized','outerposition',(0 0 1 1))"); //opens up matlab figure window
engEvalString(m_pEngine, "plot(Degrees,SinGraph,'r',Degrees,CosGraph,'b'),grid minor,title('our Matlab Plot')");

system("pause");
}
```

it runs well and I can get the correct results. that means the environment setting in my computer is correct. but when run the code below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 141; i++)    
    {
        x.push_back(((-141 / 2 + 1 - 1+i)*0.0003));
        y.push_back(((-141 / 2 + 1 - 1+i)*0.0003));
    }

engine *m_pEngine;
m_pEngine = engOpen("null"); //open matlab engine

mxArray *xxx = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, 141, mxREAL);
memcpy((void*)mxGetM(xxx), &x, sizeof(double)*x.size());
engPutVariable(m_pEngine, "x", xxx);


mxArray *yyy = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, 141, mxREAL);
memcpy((void*)mxGetM(yyy), &y, sizeof(double)*y.size());
engPutVariable(m_pEngine, "y", yyy);
```

it breaks for: Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFFB193AA69 (msvcr120d.dll) in PlanarforwardC.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0000000000000001.
and it also says that:
'PlanarforwardC.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\bin\win64\libmwcholmod.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'PlanarforwardC.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\bin\win64\graphics_util.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'PlanarforwardC.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\bin\win64\libmwplatform_res.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'PlanarforwardC.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msimg32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'PlanarforwardC.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\bin\win64\libmwamd.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'PlanarforwardC.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\bin\win64\libmwcolamd.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'PlanarforwardC.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\bin\win64\libmwblas.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'PlanarforwardC.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\bin\win64\libmwlapack.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'PlanarforwardC.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\SHCore.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'PlanarforwardC.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\bin\win64\libmwbinder.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'PlanarforwardC.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\bin\win64\libmwompwrapper.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
DBGHELP: Symbol Search Path: C:\Users\Gabrielle\Desktop\PlanarforwardC\x64\Debug
DBGHELP: C:\Users\Gabrielle\Desktop\PlanarforwardC\x64\Debug\m_interpreter.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: C:\Users\Gabrielle\Desktop\PlanarforwardC\x64\Debug\dll\m_interpreter.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: C:\Users\Gabrielle\Desktop\PlanarforwardC\x64\Debug\symbols\dll\m_interpreter.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: y:\R2012bd\build\matlab\bin\win64\m_interpreter.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: m_interpreter - export symbols
DBGHELP: C:\Users\Gabrielle\Desktop\PlanarforwardC\x64\Debug\msvcr90.amd64.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: C:\Users\Gabrielle\Desktop\PlanarforwardC\x64\Debug\dll\msvcr90.amd64.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: C:\Users\Gabrielle\Desktop\PlanarforwardC\x64\Debug\symbols\dll\msvcr90.amd64.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: msvcr90.amd64.pdb - file not found

```
memcpy((void*)mxGetM(xxx), &x, sizeof(xx));
```

I also tried to find the solution and use double xx[141]and double yy[141]replace vector x and vector y.

```
mxArray *xxx = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, num_x, mxREAL);
memcpy((void*)mxGetM(xxx), (void*)xx, sizeof(xx));
engPutVariable(m_pEngine, "x", xxx);


mxArray *yyy = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, num_x, mxREAL);
memcpy((void*)mxGetM(yyy), (void*)yy, sizeof(double)*y.size());
engPutVariable(m_pEngine, "y", yyy);
```

it still didn't work.
can anyone give me some suggestions about this? I tested line by line and the problem is in :

many thanks

Comment: I'd suggest that you store the values returned by `mxGetM(xxx)` and `mxGetm(yyy)` into temporary variables, and use a debugger to inspect them, or else print them out. That may help to pin down the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mxGetM` returns the size of the array. This size is used as an pointer in `memcpy`, which definitely leads to an invalid memory address.

Comment: I should use the mxGetPr to get each element in the array. in this problem, I want to get the element from x,  y array and temp array(a 2d array didn't shown above) and use them to call figure function in Matlab. which function should I use to get these elements?